# JQuery Mobile + WebApi + PhoneGap

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova, asp.net-web-api

I am about to create a JQM + WebAPI + PhoneGap solution. But I am not sure how to handle the authorization part given that webapi is not designed to support session state.

I can use an ajax call to the webapi to complete the login process but then how do we know if a user is logged in on subsequent requests from the client? Do we attach the userId in the HTTP header of each page? If so, how do we do this in an efficient manner?

Comment: Hello @su8898 do you have sample code of Jquery Mobile + WebAPI (calling) + Phonegap please send or give the url something like helpful to learn I am new to this techno so. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @0MV1 we ended up using owin oauth2 authentication for this project. Unfortunately, I don't have an example to post here. But you can google dotNet oauth and token based authentication and get plenty of examples in msdn and third party sites. Cheers.

Comment: ohhh that's ok thanks for reply @su8898

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Web API ample of options for user authentication and authorization. Watch this video by Dominick Baier to get a sense of options that you have:

- [Securing ASP.NET Web APIs](http://vimeo.com/43603474)